# Bootstrap single file upload and submission button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make a button on user profile that will allow the user to choose file and after the file has been chosen, it will be uploaded with the same button.

I want the button appearance as that defined by the code below:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary form-control"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-camera'></span> Change Photo</button>
```

I want to change it into:

```
<input type='Image' onchange="this.form.submit()"/>
```

But with bootstrap classes and `<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-camera'></span> Change Photo` instead of 'submit' text on button.

How can I do it?

Comment: So do you want the form to submit after they add an image or when they click the button? If it is after they add an image then you shouldn't need to change anything just have JS check for the image then submit the form. If it is the other then idk if onchange would be what you want. Maybe check image and then hide show buttons with JS

Comment: <input type='Image' onchange='this.form.submit()'> shows a button with a text "submit". I want to change this "submit" with 'change image' along with camera glyph-icon.

Comment: Why use the input? Why not <button type='submit'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-camera'></span></button>. Then just use JS to hide and show it?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the text text inside of the button you can use JavaScripts innerHTML function to set the value, but you will have to include the span.

```
button = getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary form-control")[0];
button.innerHTML="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-camera'></span> Change Photo";
```

This assumes that you only have one object with that exact class on the page. If you have more you will have to add the logic to select the correct button.

If you need to do something with the file that is loaded you will need to have some sort of server side language or scripting language since this can not be done in HTML and CSS alone.

Comment: <input type='Image' onchange='this.form.submit()'> shows a button with a text "submit". I want to change this "submit" with 'change image' along with camera glyph-icon

Comment: If you want to change the text use <button value="change image" ...> to have a different value. If you can find the container for the button then you can replace any of the HTML inside with innerHTML.